# density of zeroes of Epstein zeta functions on vertical strips

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, zeta-functions

There are many results (e.g. Davenport and Heilbronn) asserting that Epstein zeta functions in general have zeroes outside the line $\mathrm{Re\ } s = n/4$. Is there any result about the density of their zeroes on vertical strips?

One motivation for this question is a recent result of Str\"ombergsson and S\"odergren that the distribution of the zero-free region of a random Epstein zeta function converges weakly to something related to the Poisson distribution. So I was wondering if something similar could be proved with the distribution of zeroes.